# bundling failed: Error: While resolving module `metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient`

Tags: react-native

I have created a new project called metro. when I run it, this error appears on my cli nodejs:

error: bundling failed: Error: While resolving module `metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient`, the Haste package `metro` was found. However the module `src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient` could not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `D:\programming\react native\metro\src\lib\bundle-modules\HMRClient(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
- `D:\programming\react native\metro\src\lib\bundle-modules\HMRClient\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`

  - `at resolveHasteName (D:\programming\react native\metro\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:236:9)`
  - `at Object.resolve (D:\programming\react native\metro\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:103:20)`
  - `at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\programming\react native\metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:143:31)`
  - `at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\programming\react native\metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)`
  - `at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\programming\react native\metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)`
  - `at Object.resolve (D:\programming\react native\metro\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42)`
  - `at dependencies.map.result (D:\programming\react native\metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:399:31)`
  - `at Array.map (<anonymous>)`
  - `at resolveDependencies (D:\programming\react native\metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:18)`
  - `at D:\programming\react native\metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:269:33`

my react-native version is **0.59.8**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becouse I named this project metro the problem had occured. I create a new project with new name the problem is solved.

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck in the same issue,
So what I did was:

- Find the file at the path: `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/HMRClient.js`
- Change the line: `const MetroHMRClient = require('metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient');`
- To: `const MetroHMRClient = require('../../../@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient');`

Was the only thing that worked for me, the only issue is that if you reinstall de node_modules you will need to replace the line again. Because that I added this script to my package.json:

```
"postinstall": "sed -i '' \"s#metro#../../../@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro#g\" ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/HMRClient.js"
```

The above script takes care of the replacing after each new npm install

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after updating react-native to **v0.59.8**.

What I ended up doing was adding a dev dependency to metro package with `npm install --save-dev metro` which is currently at **v0.54.1**.

This solved it for me!